Don't understand this error in simple code
So I'm trying to write a code in Goggle Apps Script that will automatically make a new google spreadsheet with a name and a date based off the current date + 2 weeks, and I keep getting this error
Exception: The parameters ((class),null) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
I can't figure out why this is happening. As you can see I have a few point where the console verifies that the dateToFormat variable is an object and functioning correctly, but as soon as it goes into the var formattedDate line, it breaks.  Here's the code:
function createNewSheetWithDate() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Get today's date and add two weeks
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14);
  // Format the date (optional, customize the format as needed)
  console.log(typeof currentDate);
  var dateToFormat = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
  console.log(typeof dateToFormat);
  console.log(dateToFormat.getFullYear());
  console.log(dateToFormat);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateToFormat, null);
  // Create the new sheet name with the formatted date
  var newSheetName = "Inventory - " + formattedDate;
  // Insert a new sheet and set its name
  var newSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(newSheetName);
}

I'v tried everything I can think of to fix this, but I'm not really advanced in terms of programming/coding, so maybe there's just some simple thing I don't know about

You did not specify the time zone or date format.
Change
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateToFormat, null);

To (or whatever you want it to look like)
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateToFormat, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");


Ah thanks so much. I figured it'd be something simple lol
